# What are the performance implications of updating multiple fields using positional operator in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm storing documents in MongoDB with the following format:

```
{  
    "id" : "123",  
    "tenure" : "360",  
    "details" : [  
        {  
            "trancheID" : "8087ed47-6e94-4733-ab0d-379ad420fbe2",  
            "amount" : "26000",  
            "status" : 2  
        },  
        {  
            "trancheID" : "096856fc-dac4-4dc9-af36-3764ffb9ab3b",  
            "amount" : "26000",  
            "status" : 2  
        },  
        {  
            "trancheID" : "45752678-04e6-490c-9836-d6c4a361e1d0",  
            "amount" : "26000",  
            "status" : 1  
        }  
    ]  
}
```

When updating specific fields in the document, what is the right way to set the new values when the fields are accessed using positional operator `$` ?

In this example, I want to update `amount` and `status` of the third element i.e. the find condition will be

> { "details.trancheID" : "45752678-04e6-490c-9836-d6c4a361e1d0" }

To update the fields, I have two ways:

1. Construct the new object at client (java application) and use `$set` on the entire object,

   > { "$set" : { "details.$" : { // full object here } }

So, positional operator will select the first matching element (using condition on `trancheID`) and set the updated object. In this approach, I have to send the entire object (whose size can go up to 2KB) to MongoDB from the application.

2. Set only the fields which have to be updated in the query,

   > { "$set" : { "details.$.amount" : 50000", "details.$.status" : 3 } }

In this case, positional operator has to act twice. My concern is that does this incur any performance loss if multiple fields are set using positional operator ? Here, only two fields are being updated. But it can go up to 5-6 fields, and the number of elements in `details` array can be a lot (50 in some cases).

Right now, the field `trancheID` is not an indexed field, but I am thinking of having it as a Sparse Index. Assuming that it is an indexed field, which approach will be good ?

Also, if you can point me to some resources where I can read and understand the inner workings of MongoDB (like how positional operator works internally), that will be very helpful. Thanks!

I'm using MongoDB 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My concern is that does this incur any performance loss if multiple fields are set using positional operator ?

No performance loss. Once the matching element is found, MongoDB maps '$' to array subscript of that element. Therefore, in your case, the second way is recommended since it saves the cost of transferring the whole element over network, twice. Also, it is more straightforward.

As always, I suggest you to test both ways with your production data set to see how performance differs. In fact, I don't think you should worry about the performance difference between these two ways unless your test proves that the difference is significant.

> Also, if you can point me to some resources where I can read and understand the inner workings of MongoDB (like how positional operator works internally), that will be very helpful. Thanks!

MongoDB is an open source project. On [github](https://github.com/mongodb) you will find source code for MongoDB server as well as a number of tools. As for '$set' and positional operator, you may want to look into [UpdateDriver::update](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.2.10/src/mongo/db/ops/update_driver.cpp#L219), [ModifierSet::prepare](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.2.10/src/mongo/db/ops/modifier_set.cpp#L107), and [ModifierSet::apply](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r3.2.10/src/mongo/db/ops/modifier_set.cpp#L179) of R3.2.10 source code.

> I'm using MongoDB 3.0.

Please note that current stable release is 3.2. And, 3.4 is coming soon.